# My .xls document is opening in apple numbers with all of the data in one column

Tags: excel, vbscript, numbers, xls

I've got a document written in vbscript that generates a .xls document. In the code the data is separated by vbtab's. It opens normally in excel, but in apple numbers all of the data is in one really wide column with the data separated with tabs, as in several spaces. It looks fine, but I need the data to be in different columns so that it can be sorted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205391), Numbers can import the following formats:

- Numbers ’08 or later
- Microsoft Excel - Office Open XML (.xlsx) and Office 97 or later (.xls)
- Comma Separated Values (CSV)
- Tab-delimited text files

It's likely that the issue is that your "xls" file isn't actually Excel formatted.  Try changing the file extension of the output file to .txt and opening it in Numbers.

Depending on your data, I would recommend you just output [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) instead.